# Recovering encrypted word using dictonary in python

Tags: python, search, encryption, dictionary, rsa

I'm trying to recover an RSA encrypted 5 character word using a forward search dictionary attack in Python but having difficulty. The word was encrypted in 2 24 bit blocks (3648141 5604637) padding last block with a space

```
e = 5
n = 21508387

table = {}
for ptext in range(65,90):
    ctext = pow(ptext,e,n)
    table[ctext] = ptext
    print table
```

I know I need to do the above so that it decrypts all combinations 3 characters long AAA AAB... ZZA ZZB, etc but what I have only decrypts single characters A B C.. X Y Z so how do I get it to decrypt 3 chars at a time?

The print out I get is lots of lines that feature things like {8521919L: 65} {7688462L: 66, 8521919L: 65}
but I can't see my blocks in the results and I assume that the number have the colon is the ASCII?

Can I please get some help with this, any advice?
Thank you

Comment: `{7688462L: 66, 8521919L: 65} ` is a python dict and means: 7688462L maps to 66, and 8521919L maps to 65.

Answer (score 1):

Generate all three-letter combinations, encode them as integer, apply the pow function, report when they match your encrypted message.

The most obvious way to iterate through all three letter combinations is with three nested loops instead of the one you have right now.

Comment: the pow function is already being applied but to one letter combination but not sure how to iterate through the combinations 3 times as using the following doesn't work e = 11
n = 22734533

table = {}
for ptext in range(65,90):
    ctext = pow(ptext,e,n)
    table[ctext] = ptext
    for ptext in range(65,90):
        ctext = pow(ptext,e,n)
    table[ctext] = ptext
    for ptext in range(65,90):
        ctext = pow(ptext,e,n)
    table[ctext] = ptext
    for ptext in range(65,90):
        ctext = pow(ptext,e,n)
    table[ctext] = ptext
    print table

Comment: You must apply it to the combination of all three letters at once. Otherwise, you'll get a different result. I.e. convert the three chars into *one* number (a "block" - the encryption is done blockwise!), then encode it.

Comment: How do I loop just 3 times though before it reaches the pow I don't know very little about Python and wasn't asked to learn it for what I am doing the focus is on the the security

Comment: *Nesting* three loops is the same in pretty much any language.

Comment: @Smush: I'm not sure I should mention it, but the `itertools` module has a `product` method that is a little cleaner. But then I understand nested loops and you really should also.

Comment: @GregS I am still trying to figure nested for loop out. How do I get the thing to loop 3 times I work it out

Comment: not three times total, but you need to _nest_ three loops within each other - literally.

Comment: @Anonymouse But doing this doesnt work  as I get a lines of {12462520L: 89} 
e = 11
n = 22734533
i = 0
table = {}
for ptext in range(65,90):
    for ptext in range(65,90):
        for ptext in range(65,90):
    ctext = pow(ptext,e,n)
    table[ctext] = ptext
    print table

Comment: compute the proper 24-bit value from the three of them.

Comment: ok dont overwrite pxtext so I tried this and still no luck 
e = 11
n = 22734533
i = 0
table = {}
for ztext in range(65,90):
    for atext in range(65,90):
        for btext in range(65,90):
            ptext = ztext+atext+btext
            ctext = pow(ptext,e,n)
    table[ctext] = ptext
    print table

Comment: your formula for computing ptext ist wrong. rethink how a 3-letter string might be encoded sensibly (it's not the sum of the char values)

Comment: Are you going to help me any more than that because I have been trying for some time and still get no luck

Comment: Well no but could possibly guide me in the right direction like what I need to read into

Comment: I'm trying all the time... think about character encoding as numbers .

Comment: Task A): write a program that produces AAA, AAB, AAC  Task B) find a way to compute the common representation of ABC as 24-bit number
Combine these two, and you are largely set. (add a-z and whitespace, and skip the dictionary, just look for the two numbers you need.)

Comment: I need to try to convert this code to use all combinations starting AAA using for loops now right?
bk1 = (ord('H') << 8) + ord('e')
bk2 = (ord('l') << 8) + ord('l')
bk3 = (ord('o') << 8) + ord(' ')
cbk1 = pow(bk1,3,70747)
cbk2 = pow(bk2,3,70747)
cbk3 = pow(bk3,3,70747)
print cbk1, cbk2, cbk3

Comment: That looks a lot better already - except you are now doing 16 bit, and your task (apparently) was to use 24 bits.

Comment: ok it's changed a bit now and I'm told this is right except I get the error ctext = pow(ord(bk1),e,n)
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 3 found.

New code is 
e=5
n=21508387
c1=3648141
table={}
for j in range(65,90):
    for k in range(65,90):
        for l in range(65,90):
            bk1 = chr(j>>8)+chr(k>>16)+chr(l>>24)
            ctext = pow(ord(bk1),e,n)
            table[ctext] = bk1


print table[3648141]

Comment: Your chr and ord use is a mess and incorrect. The shifts  also... Whoever told you this is right did not pay much attention. I think you have identified all the operators you need, but your logic is a mess.

Comment: It was my tutor who told me this was almost correct. What do you mean logic is a mes why?

Comment: You use almost everything exactly the opposite way it should be used. *Rethink your mathematics first, not the code*!